# Prompting registration after creating content but before save

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to implement a page using Django where the user is able to create content, hit submit, and then is prompted to register or login if they are not currently logged-in. One of the fields in the model for the content references the user, so they must be logged-in to create it, however I want them to be able to input all of the data before they are prompted with logging-in. I have used the @loginrequired decorator on the view, but that forced the user to be logged-in before they create the content.  Here is the view currently:

```
def search(request):
 form = LocationInput()
 if request.method == "POST":
    form = LocationInput(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        t = Trip(trip_name = form.cleaned_data['city'])
        t.user = request.user
        t.save()
        form.save()
        l = Location.objects.get(google_id=form.cleaned_data['google_id'])
        l.trips.add(t)
        l.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/trips/')
 return render(request, 'frontpage/search.html', {'form': form})
```

It loads the form, creates an object that needs a user associated with it so I need to register the user but keep the data from LocationInput(request.POST) until after the user has registered. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two options:

1. Allow `NULL` for user reference, save the content in a state "pending user login or sign up", and store the ID of the content object in a [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/). Vacuum "old" contents with no user reference on a regular basis.
2. Save the whole data of the form in a session.

I like the first one better since you, as a superuser, have access to the content even if the user didn't login or signup, and if the user contact you later telling you he had troubles signing in, you will be able to help and recover the content he submitted. While if everything is stored in session, once the session is deleted, it's all lost.